# Groovy AST transformations not recognized in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, groovy

NetBeans doesn't seem to recognize Groovy AST transformations (e.g. `@TupleConstructor`) on Groovy classes. If I define a class like this:

```
@TupleConstructor
class Person {
    String name
    int age
}
```

I expect to be able to write a constructor call like this:

```
Person person = new Person("John", 30);
```

This does indeed compile and work. However, NetBeans IDE marks this as an error. This seems to be true for all AST transformations (also tested with `@Singleton`). As expected, code completion also doesn't work for "additional" funationality added via AST transformations.

Is this a known bug in NetBeans, or do I need to configure anything? Is there any workaround?

---

I'm using NetBeans 8.1. I'm working with a Maven project, with a dependency on Groovy 2.4.6.

Comment: IntelliJ recognizes all ASTs even in the community edition, if you have the possibility to use it.

Comment: Thank you, I may give that a try.

Comment: @SputNick ... May be yo uneed to check if your project is actually  _using_ Groovy 2.4.  I'm sorting through this issue myself.  I put this line in my Groovy file: `println "Groovy version = " + GroovySystem.getVersion()` Ther version bundled with Netbeans v8.1 is -- Printed as: "Groovy version = 2.1.7".  Otherwise you may need to check what the POM does.